# How can I make a master page for all of my pages like default page in Zebble for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I created a new blank page as I read on Zebble documentation website like below code, but I need to use this for all of my pages and I do not want to repeat that design on all of my pages. And when I try to build my project an error occurs like below:

```
<z-Component z-type="Page1" z-base="Page" z-namespace="UI.Pages"
z-partial="true" Title="Page 1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./../.zebble-schema.xml">

  <Stack Id="Header" Direction="Horizontal">
     <Button  Text="MyToogleMenuBtn" />
     <TextView Text="MyPageTitle" />
     <Button Text="AddBtn" />
  </Stack>
  <Stack Id="Body">

  </Stack>
  <Stack Id="Footer">
     <Button Id="ConfirmBtn"  />
  </Stack>

/z-Component>
```

And the error is:

[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrz3A.png)

But I do not know where should I add the title property.

Comment: Try including the error as a part of your post, this makes the post easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

For using this page as **template** for your other pages you just need to specify it as the `z-base`:

```
<z-Component z-type="MyChildPage" z-base="MyTemplate" ...
```

As for the error you should remove the `Title="Page 1"` because there is no `Title` property in your current page